Does a terminal Gorenstein cDV singularity imply a DuVal singularity on the general elephant?
I am reading through Kollár and Mori's book "Birational geometry of algebraic varieties". Now I was trying to understand Theorem 5.43, I only state the relevant part for the question.

Let $(0\in X)$ be a normal isolated 3-fold singularity. Assume that $K_X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-Carties of index r. Then $(0\in X)$ is terminal iff a general member $H\in |-K_X|$ containing 0 is Du Val.

Now the theorem is not proved and two references are given: Miles Reid's "Young person's guide to canonical singularities" and Mori's "On 3-dimensional terminal singularities".
In this statement there are no restrictions to the index of the canonical divisor. Nevertheless, on Mori's article only the case $r>1$ is treated. In Reid's when this is discussed in (6.4) and (6.5) he makes use of the classification of quotient cDV singularities, i.e. assumes $r>1$. Now I would like to know what happens in the Gorenstein case, i.e. index is 1, all the references to this theorem I've seen go back to this two papers and explicitly mention this to be true, see for example Kollár and Mori's "Classification of Three-Dimensional Flips".
I am therefore asking for some reference to this case or some explanation of why it is trivial enough to not be mentioned.

Both the Gorenstein and the non-Gorenstein case are in Main Theorem (I) in Reid's "Minimal Models of Canonical 3-Folds", (0.6). If you prefer, this is also in Theorem (a) in Reid's "Young person's guide to canonical singularities", (3.2).
Even though there is a quotient by a finite cyclic group $\mu_r$, the order $r$ is allowed to be $1$.

While I am aware in general we allow $r=1$ (as in the references you pointed out), what is not clear to me is that the specific fact I cite is shown for $r=1$. This relies on theorem by Mori cited in (6.1) which explicitly assumes $r>1$. For example, if we take this classification from (6.4) $cE_n$ and $cD_n$ Gorenstein singularities should not exist. l may be mistaken but: the idea is to classify quotient cDV singularities in terms of the cDV and the cDV case is seen as simple enough. I do not know how to get the description on the smoothing of a cDV singularity.

The Gorenstein case of the specific fact you cite is NOT proved in section 6. The Gorenstein case is proved in section 3, with some of the finer details appearing only in the original paper "Minimal Models of Canonical 3-Folds". The proof of the Gorenstein case does NOT use that paper of Mori. The paper of Mori was published two years after "Minimal Models of Canonical 3-Folds". We can take r = 1 in the two citations I gave. We CANNOT take r = 1 in (6.1).

I still do not see where the sections of the anticanonical bundle are mentioned in section 3. But I guess I can trust that it is true.
